# tkinter GUI python simple app that i made for my first time, fix errors

Tags: python, tkinter

It is my first tkinter GUI app in python, I got errors. So pls help.

Dont rename the variables as much as you can pls.
I used many resources so it may be hard to understand some codes.

```
class app (Frame):
    root=Tk()

    def __init__(self):
        main_win = tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("encryption and decryption app")
        main_win.txt_box = Text(Tk(), hieght=2, width=10)
        main_win.txt_box.pack()
        main_win.passw_box = Text(root, hieght=2, width=10)
        main_win.passw_box.pack()

        def encrypt(self):
            data = self.txt_box.get("1.0", END)
            password = self.passw_box.get("1.0", END)
            encrypted_text = ""
            for i in range(len(data)):
                new = chr(abs(ord(password[(i % len(password))]) + ord(data[i])))
                encrypted_text = encrypted_text + new
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("encrypted text in utf-8",encrypted_text)

        def decrypt (self):
            data = self.txt_box.get("1.0", END)
            password = self.passw_box.get("1.0", END)
            decrypted_text = ""
            for i in range(len(data)):
                new = chr(abs(ord(password[(i % len(password))]) - ord(data[i])))
                decrypted_text = decrypted_text + new
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("decrypted text in utf-8",decrypted_text)
        main_win.en_button = tk.Button(self, text = "encrypt", width = 25,command = encrypt(main_win))
        main_win.de_button = tk.Button(self, text="decrypt", width=25, command= decrypt(main_win))





def main():
    app().mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expext to get an app that decrypt and encrypt text. Note that the encrypt and decrypt functions needs a password and text.

Comment: What have you tried already and what is the error that is occuring?

Comment: "I got errors" is too vague. Please [edit] your question and be specific.

Comment: This site isn't for people to do your work for you! At least take us to dinner first and look at [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing arguments to a button command requires a lambda function.

Refactor your commands from

```
command = cmd(param)
```

to

```
command = lambda: cmd(param)
```

should fix the button command issue.